# Use Ajax in Prototype.js to load PART of an external page into a div

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

I'm looking for a way to load a part of an external page (possibly selected by an id in the external page) into a div. Something similar to Ajax.Updater, but with the option of specifying an id to look for in the external page.

Does anything like this exist in prototype. I've been googling for examples without luck. If I can't find it soon I'll have to do some "gymnastics" with Ajax.Request and some function tied to onSuccess.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do something like this, though it is by no means an elegant solution.

```
new Ajax.Updater("container", 'www.babes.com', {
  onSuccess: function() {
    $("container").update( $('idOfSomeLoadedElement') );
  }
});
```

I don't think there is an actual elegant way of doing this purely in js. Ideally, you'd make your AJAX request only for what you need. You might be able to do some server-side stuff to lop out what you don't need (basically, offload the onsuccess functionality above to the server).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of AJAX you might get by with an iframe.

```
// dollar function calls Element.extend
var iframe = $(document.createElement('iframe'));

// control how and what it loads
iframe.addEventListener('onLoad', function() {
    $('container').update(iframe.contentDocument.select('#someID').first());
});
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'http://URL');

// add it as invisible, content isn't loaded until then
iframe.setAttribute('hidden', true);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

From a minimal test it's clear that you'll have to be as concious about cross-origin policies as any AJAX method, that is, it's a PITA.